# How to get Android HTTP requests?

Tags: android, networking, sniffer

I would like to get the HTTP POST and GET requests of Android applications and the browser. How can I sniff the network traffic?

It is important that I can also see the request which are caused by running Android applications.

Comment: You can use **[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)** to sniff the network on an interface. However, this doesn't typically run on a handheld device; it is desktop software. I'd suggest putting this on the server that is serving the POST/GET requests.

Comment: Is there no other way? Maybe an app?

Answer (score 4):

If you are rooted, you can get a Wireshark port for Android [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark). You can record all network traffic on your phone, take the tcpdump files, and read them with a desktop version of Wireshark.

You can also use the android emulator on computers. Start the [emulator via command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) and add the `-tcpdump` tag. Use `adb push my_app.apk` to install your application onto the device. This will save a tcpdump file onto your PC, which can also be read with Wireshark.

For live tracking, you can also proxy your android connections through something like [burp proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html).

Comment: Is there a documentary on  how to use shark for root and how to analyse the requests? I do not know how to get it work in background?

Comment: Open up the app (it should be called "Shark"). Then just hit the start button and it'll start recording network traffic. Do whatever you need to do on the phone (eg, use the applications you want to sniff). When you're done, open Shark again and hit the stop button. Then plug your phone into your computer and there should be .pcap files on your phone (usually root SD card directory), which can be read with wireshark from your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the emulator with the command `-avd Adfmf -http-proxy http://SYSTEM_IP:PORT`. I used HTTP Analyzer, but it should work for anything else. More details can be found here: http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/04/intercept-http-requests-sent-from-app.html

To track browser requests coming from the Emulator, you can refer:
http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/04/intercept-http-requests-sent-from.html